# How to disable changestate tracking for a sub-entity in boilerplate AppService

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using aspnet core & ef core with boilerplate and would like to disable the  changestate tracking for a sub-entity. How do I this this within AppService (ie AsyncCrudAppService).

For example:

Entity:

```
[Table("tblCategory")]
public class Category : FullAuditedEntity<int>, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public const int MaxCodeLength = 128;
    public const int MaxNameLength = 2048;

    public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(MaxCodeLength)]
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(MaxNameLength)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

Dto:

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Category))]
public class CategoryDto : FullAuditedEntityDto<int>
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(Category.MaxCodeLength)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(Category.MaxNameLength)]
    public  string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public  int GroupId { get;  set; }

    [DisableValidation]
    public GroupDto Group{ get;  set; }

}
```

AppService Update Method:

```
public override async Task<CategoryDto> Update(CategoryDto input)
{
    var cat = await _categoryManager.GetA(input.Id);

    MapToEntity(input, cat);

    //I'd like to disable the tracking of cat.Group here ?

    await _categoryManager.UpdateA(cat);

    return await Get(input);
}
```

I'd like to disable the change detection for cat.Group, how do I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use AsNoTracking

Comment: Thanks vivek, that worked. I use the following to load the category entity:  await _categoryRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(id); It seems to always load the Group Entity, is there anyway to stop it loading Group Entity ?

Comment: Try removing `virtual`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AsNoTracking when loading resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Tracking can be skipped by adding `.AsNoTracking()` to the call.

For example:

```
var cat = await _yourDbContext.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync(m => m.Id == input.Id);
```

Which is fine for results that will not be edited during it's lifetime.